# Setting chart dimensions without calling .resize()

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

Is it possible to programmatically set the dimensions of a chart before rendering? I have 10-20 charts on one page. Rendering the charts is a performance bottleneck, and having to resize the charts means that they are needlessly rendered twice. It would be a big time saver if I could just specify the size before they are rendered via style or parameter.

I have tried:

- Putting the Charts in a styled chart widget.
- Adding style to both the chart widget and the chart itself via dom-style.
- Setting the "plotArea" attribute on the chart.
- Adding "height" and "width" attributes as arguments to the addPlot() function
- Going through the source code to find a parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: For future reference, the best method for doing what Richard suggested is using the chart.surface.setDimensions() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the chart renders, it should create a surface based on the underlying node that the chart is built off of. So by changing the styling of the node that your chart is using, then the chart should render based on that node.